# При поиске через телеграмм бот (библиотека aiogram) в БД выдает такую ошибку: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 126

Tags: python, sqlite, aiogram

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добрый день. Делал запрос к этой БД не через телеграмм бота, все данные выдавало без проблем, а через бота выдает ошибку - Can't parse entities: can't find end of italic entity at byte offset 126.
Для поиска и вывода в телеграмм использую код:

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM shopCentre WHERE Name3 = '{Kad_Num}'")
records = cursor.fetchall()
global num_row
num_row = len(records)
if Kad_Num == '/Stop_Search':
    await message.answer('Поиск завершен.')
    await state.finish()
else:
    if num_row == 1:
        for result in records:
            await message.answer('Количество найденных записей:\n' + str(num_row) + '\n\nДля завершения поиска, нажмите на /Stop_Search', parse_mode="MarkdownV2")
            await message.answer('Наименование торгового центра:\n'+str(result[1]) + "\n\n" + 'Адрес объекта налогообложения:\n'+str(result[4])+ "\n\n" +'Вид объекта:\n'+str(result[2]) + "\n\n" + 'Общая площадь объекта недвижимости, кв.м.:\n'+str(result[8]))
```

Приложил небольшой скрин из БД. На скрине видны синие стрелочки, которые означают - `load remaining part of the value`. Может ли быть такая ошибка из-за большой информации в ячейке таблицы, например адрес в столбце Name4. Либо проверить на формат текста, типа без курсива, жирного, что бы везде был однообразным?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Решение моего вопроса](https://qna.habr.com/q/557708)

Нашел ответ) удалил markdown

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)